# libdft_api.h:36:25: fatal error：sys/syscall.h：No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, cygwin, fatal-error

I've got a problem when compiling libdft in Windows XP.

I use cygwin terminal to compile it and I　have installed everything in devel and I　have modified the Makefile to avoid the OS check.

But when I try the make command it returns the error:

> libdft_api.h:36:25: fatal error：sys/syscall.h：No such file or
>   directory

I tried to find syscall.h but it doesn't exist as below.

```
Administrator@simon-4b7c3fa57 /cygdrive/c/libdft_linux-i386/src
$ cygcheck -l cygwin | grep syscall.h
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. From what I've gathered from Google, `syscall.h` is a system file specific to the architecture of your machine. Cygwin doesn't emulate a Linux machine its only some tools and APIs to create a look and feel of one, so that's why the file doesn't exist. For example: In a full Linux OS it could be found in `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/`

You'll need to use a similar file found in windows somewhere or try and compile your code in a Linux VM.